# C# MySQL Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello I found this code snippet for Adding Values to MySQL Commands in C#

```
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_mitarbeiter (Vorname) VALUES (?name)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", mitarbeiter);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I want to add data to more than one coloumn, but if i try it like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Projektid, "?projektnummer", Projektnummer, "?anlageDatumProjekt", Projektanlage, "?auftraggeberProjekt",Projektauftraggeber, "?bezeichnungProjekt", Projektbezeichnung, "?nachAufwand", nachAufwand, "?bemerkungProjekt",Projektbemerkung, "?matFremdKalk", matfremdkalk, "?maStundenKalk",mastundenkalk, "?maKostenKalk", makostenkalk, "?maZuschlagFixKalk", mazuschlagfixkalk, "?maZuschlagVarKalk",mazuschlagvarkalk, "?maschStundenKalk",maschstundenkalk, "?maschKostenKalk",maschkostenkalk, "?maschZuschlagFixKalk",maschzuschlagfixkalk, "?maschZuschlagVarKalk",maschzuschlagvarkalk, "?summeAuftragKalk",summeauftragkalk, "?matFremdErfasst",matfremderfasst, "?maStundenerfasst",mastundenerfasst, "?maSelbstkostenErfasst",maselbstkostenerfasst, "?maschStundenErfasst",maschstundenerfasst, "?maschKostenVariabelErfasst",maschkostenvariabelerfasst, "?maschKostenFixErfasst",maschkostenfixerfasst, "?gemeinKostenBerechnet",gemeinkostenberechnet, "?abschlagRechnungErfasst",abschlagrechnungerfasst, "?rabatt", rabatt);
```

it just says that

> No Overload for AddWithValue with 52 Arguments.

What do I have to change to get the code running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try to add all your 52 parameter and their values with **one** `AddWithValue` method. You *can't* do that.

First of all, you need to define all your parameters in your command with your column names like;

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tb_mitarbeiter (Vorname, id, projectnummber....) VALUES (?name, ?id, ?projektnummer....)";
```

Then you need to add all your 52 parameters in a 52 different `AddWithValue` method.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", mitarbeiter);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Projektid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projektnummer", Projektnummer);
...
...
```

Or add all of them in a one `MySqlParameterCollection` and add this collection to your command as;

```
command.Parameters.Add(MyParameterCollection);
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me, the tb mitarbeiter was a copy mistake there is a tbprojects with coloums for each value

Answer (score 0):

Try to only add one value per AddWidthValue like

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", mitarbeiter);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Projektid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?projektnummer", Projektnummer)
```

and so on.

Sven

Answer (score 0):

You need to add each sql paramater on its own. An example would be in your case;

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", Projektid);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pr1ojektnummer", Projektnummer);
```

finally call the

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```